# Syntax error in bash only in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

```
declare -a identifications=(
'10760260000119 - 34234324' # ok
)

declare -a years=(
  2010
  2011
  2012
  2013
  2014
)

for identification in "${identifications[@]}"
do
  for year in "${years[@]}"
  do
    downloader --type=CNPJ --format=XLS --identification=${identification:0:14} --password=${identification:16:20} --competence=${year} --output="$identification - $year"
  done
done
```

I created this bash script using a MacBook Pro Yosemite 10 and now i'm trying to use in a ubuntu 14 server (AWS) and is causing a syntax error:

```
bash/2010.sh: 1: bash/2010.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Maybe i need install some package?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your file? If not, add one.

Comment: I added.. same error. I'm using sh bash_program.sh

Comment: Either make it executable, or run it like `bash bash_program.sh`.

Comment: Now is working. Post as an answer Tom!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your system, the program that is run when you use `sh` can vary. You're basically saying "use the default shell, whatever that is", so you should only use this if you're limiting yourself to POSIX-standard shell.

If `sh` means `bash` on your system, then it will be run in a *compatibility mode*, which can result in certain features (such as arrays) being disabled (I say "can" as I'm not sure of the details - this varies between platforms as you've seen).

Long story short, if you want to use bash features, you should run it like `bash bash_program.sh` instead.

Also, I think it's good practice to add the shebang line to the top of the file `#!/bin/bash`, make it executable and run it like `./bash_program.sh`. This clearly states the intent at the top of the script.

Comment: On recent Ubuntus, `sh` is not `bash` in compatibility mode, but `dash`. It doesn't support arrays at all.

Comment: @choroba thanks, I've adjusted my answer to factor that in.